# Using "android:textAppearance" on TextView/EditText fails, but "style" works

Tags: android

This is a sample TextView in XML, which will properly apply the style `TextContactContactName` to the TextView.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/photo"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="First Last"
        style="@style/TextContactContactName"
        />
```

Now, I have some other things to set on this element, which are not text related. As such I tried to move the `TextContactContactName` and apply it via "android:textAppearance"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/photo"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="First Last"
    android:textAppearance=@style/TextContactContactName"
    />
```

Unluckily, the text formatting is not being applied.

This is how the style (stored in `res/values/styles-text.xml`) looks like:

```
<style name="TextContactContactName">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#333333</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>
```

Am I using the `textAppearance` tag wrong?

I tested on Android 2.2 - HTC Desire.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, looks like my fault. I had made a quick test:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text styled using 'style'."
        style="@style/UiTestTextView"
        />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text styled using 'textAppearance'."
        android:textAppearance="@style/UiTestTextView"
        />
```

and the styles-text.xml:

```
<style name="UiTestTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>

    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">3</item>
</style>
```

The key thing is to remember that `shadow*` elements are not text properties. And as such **will not be applied via textAppearance.**

I'm going to ask on the Android Developers Mailing list if this is desired behavior.

Comment: Have you gotten an answer from Developers? I would be glad to know it too.

Comment: To clarify is it if you include a non-text appearance attribute to a style you apply via `textAppearance` the whole style fails to be applied?

Answer (score 1):

I filed a bug report on this issue. I think I got the standard reply "the shadow is not considered part of the text appearance".

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=35887