# Right Location of "setTypeface" to avoid memoryleak

Tags: android

what is a right place to use setTypeface on listview ?
at the moment when i check logcat i see this message "Purgin 192K from font cache [23 enrtries]
is this some kinda memory leak ?
and my code :

```
 final Typeface FontText =  FontFactory.getFontfromRaw();
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
.....
     Textbox.setTypeface(FontText)
```

and my FontFactory class :

```
public class FontFactory {

private static FontFactory instance = new FontFactory ();

private FontFactory () {}

public static FontFactory getInstance() {
return instance;
}

public static Typeface getFontfromRaw() {
return Typeface.createFromAsset(AppContext.getAppContext().getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
}
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the best solution, but instead of using a TextView i use a cusom component that extends it and set the typeface from xml

Comment: can u give some direction please.

Comment: Nothing, forget what I wrote before, you can set the typeface directly from xml with `android:textAppearance=""` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337680/using-androidtextappearance-on-textview-edittext-fails-but-style-works) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for more details

Comment: I had memory problems because I set the typeface of listView items in the getView() method, that's bad, setting it in the xml will avoid useless work everytime the list scrolls. Make sure you are not doing stuff in the wrong place like I did.