# android:textColor not actually working

Tags: android, xml

[image]I have an Edittext in my application. I have set it's default color to black in the following manner in the XML:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

LAYOUT:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="scientificcalculatorapp.scientificcalculator.ScientificCalculator"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            </LinearLayout>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/Output"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:longClickable="true"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:allowUndo="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This works when I get input from my keypad but when I copy something in a different color from a different application and then paste it in this EditText, the text gets pasted in this other color and not black.

How can I standardize the color to be black regardless of whatever color I copied it in.

UPDATE:

```
output.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String yourCopiedString=output.getText().toString();
                int length = yourCopiedString.length();
                Spannable spannable= new SpannableString(yourCopiedString);
                //set color
                //set size
                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0,length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(5.0f), 0,length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                output.setText(spannable);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: What if  `backgroundColor` makes to do so ???

Comment: My background color is set to darker grey already. However if I paste green color text I get green color text in my edit text. I neither get black(what I want) or grey as you mentioned @SatanPandey a

Comment: Post your `layout` file.

Comment: what if you try to set `android:textAppearance` with a style.....maybe this helps...

Comment: Could you try to convert the string to spannableString and set color before pasting

Comment: Done, Satan Pandeya.

Comment: Hi @Opiatefuchs as you can see in the updated question I had already included the android:textAppearance and set a style. If not this, which style would you recommend?

Comment: Sure @Vinodh if you don't mind can you please give me an example?

Comment: Also @Vinodh I am not doing the pasting operation. The operation is done  with the standard Android cursor long press operations such as Cut, Copy,Translate,Assist etc. I am not explicitly defining any Paste method.

Comment: @AnuragJoshi Which color are you getting while typing, i get text with balck color in `EditText`.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your text color in `EditText` ?

Comment: Black color. That is correct(mentioned in question also). Now go to some other place and type something in green. Now copy this and paste it to the EditText. Is it in Green on Black? For me it is in Green. I want black.

Comment: Done, Satan Pandeya.

Comment: add event listener to text change event. then set text colour inside that.

Comment: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` is a system value, I guess it´s not completely defined with color, style etc. I think you have to try it with your own style. It´s just a try, I don´t know if it solves the problem. Simple example here, see the answer from Sebastian Roth and try it like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337680/using-androidtextappearance-on-textview-edittext-fails-but-style-works

Comment: PS: in that link, it´s another problem, I just wanted to show you how to use custom styles, so don´t care about the topic...

Comment: Tried that as well @IshanFernando,  But doesn't work.

Comment: Yes @Opiatefuchs I went through the page you linked to and tried the solution and defined my own textcolor(black) but still it was getting pasted in a different color(green in this case)

Comment: ok, maybe we can trick the system. The idea is, to add TextWatcher to the EditText and set the textAppearance programatically on text change. Can you try this or do you need an example of what I mean?

Comment: Can you please give an example? Thank you!

Comment: added an example....try it..

Answer (score 0):

The copy-paste behavior varies from vendor to vendor depending upon the functionality they have added.

My suggestion is, set an `onFocusChangeListener` to your `editText`, when the `EditText` loses its focus override the `textColor` again ! This is a simple work around. Try and let me know.

Update:
As you have only one, `EditText` field, it never loses the focus and the above solution needs to be little tweaked.

In the layout, add another `EditText` field. Set it's visibility to `GONE`. For the existing `EditText` field, add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`.
In your activity, to the newly added 'EditText`field, set it's input type to`TYPE_NULL`. Now, when the user presses`next`button in the keyborad, your`EditText` will loses the focus resulting in changing the textColor. This is work around, not a solution.

Comment: Hi. i tried this:                               output.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus) {
                    output.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: But getting the same green color again.

Comment: Are u able to perform mathematical operations on the content copied?

Comment: Yup. I am able to do that.

Comment: But for maintaining UI uniformity I wanted all text copied/pasted to be black.

Comment: Looks like you have only one `EditText` field and it is not losing foucs.

Comment: Hi. I tried the updated answer as well but still I get the different color.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is a try. I don´t know if it solves the problem, but need to show code. First create a style:

```
<style name="NormalText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
 </style>
```

then add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`

```
output.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

       @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

       @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

       @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


           }
}
```

create a global boolean value and ClipboardManager:

```
 private ClipboardManager clipBoard;
 private boolean addedToClipboard = false;
```

initialize and add a listener to the Manager:

```
 clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

                addedToClipboard = true;
            }
        });
```

Then do the following in AfterTextChanged:

```
    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     Log.d("TAPPJABB", "AFTER TEXT CHANGED:" + s);
     if (addedToClipboard == true) {
      String yourCopiedString = output.getText().toString();
      int length = yourCopiedString.length();
      Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(yourCopiedString);//set color
      spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(5.0f), 0, length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      addedToClipboard = false;
      output.setText(spannable);

   }
 }
```

It´s important to follow the order here to avoid infinite loop. The boolean value prevents a normal input from beeing formatted, in this example it works only for clipboard paste.

But like you mentioned, it works not if you want to paste it multiple times, what usually nobody do on one EditText. The problem here is, that we are left alone here from Google, there is no paste-listener or another solution for the editText, at least I couldn´t find anything.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay in answering but sorry, this did not work. I still get the green color after pasting.

Comment: ok one more try....try to use spannable and set this to your string before you paste

Comment: I am not programmatically doing the paste operation. I am using android:textIsSelectable="true" to automate the cut, copy, paste process.

Comment: ok, so please check the textwatcher. Maybe You can combine these two ways. The TextChangedListener should throw an event if the text is pasted. Then copy the text from the editText , make that spannable and set this to the editText

Comment: Hey. I updated the question and please check the code in the "UPDATE" section. That causes a crash.

Comment: please add the error stacktrace. It´s hard to know what causes the crash without that.

Comment: wait, sorry....I haven´t forgot that it will cause an infinite loop because everytime you set the new text, afterTextChanged will called again...my bad, sorry

Comment: damn....pretty tricky question. I need some time until this evening, must go to work but will come back soon..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130183/discussion-between-opiatefuchs-and-anurag-joshi).

Comment: Yes, I sent you a message. It kind of works but only in the first attempt.